# How do I swap array elements mapped to a cell array - matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a lattice (square array) mapped to an array of cells, how could I make it so that if I swap two array elements I have also swapped the cells mapped to those elements?

I would really appreciate all suggestions.

Thank you.

The Cells

```
l=cell(1,10000);

for i=1:10000

    l{i}=[randi(10), randi([0,2])];

end
```

---

the array

```
lattice=1:10000;
map=containers.Map(lattice,l);
lattice=reshape(lattice,100,100)';
```

---

now say I want to swap elements 1 and 2 in the array
e.g.  `lattice([1 2])=lattice([2 1])`

I also want this to swap the mapped cells so that l{2} is now l{1} and vice versa.

Any Ideas?

Comment: could you add your code?

Comment: Please give an example for the data structure and how an operation changes it.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. You have a numeric matrix, and a copy of that numeric matrix represented in a cell array. You want to make sure that if any elements in the numeric matrix are swapped, then they are also swapped in the cell array?

Comment: What purpose does the cell array serve? Obviously you've simplified the example, but I see nothing here that couldn't be done by storing indices or subscripts into `lattice`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [deal](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)?

```
[l{1}, l{2}] = deal(l{2}, l{1});
```